# -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; not working in Safari 7.1.7

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have an ul with several li.

I use this id on the ul.

```
#list {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width:500px;
color:black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #909090);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

The contents of the ul receive a gradient treatment just fine in Chrome but not Safari. In Safari, all of the li are "invisible". If I inspect and then disable the "-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;", the text will become visible albeit without the gradient (obviously).

Thoughts?

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s96bzcua/

Kind regards,

Comment: There is a bug in the official safari bug tracker. Unfortunately it looks like nobody has looked into it for the last two years:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169125

Answer (score 14):

I had this same issue. Turns out it was due to the display property. For whatever reason, Safari needs the display set to "inline" or "inline-block", but not "inline-flex".

So for me this meant changing From:
display: flex;
To:
display: inline;

Comment: I had to use inline-block, but this was great. Thanks! My live example [is here](https://blog.oleeo.com) if anyone else wants to see it in action. Without the "inline-block" declaration on the a tag, Safari would only show the first line or so and then the text was missing.

Comment: Any idea why this isn't compatible with flexbox?

Answer (score 5):

To someone coming to this, just drop `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` as it's [not a standard and is not on a standard track](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color).

Use instead `color: transparent` and wrap everything in an `@supports` to prevent color transparent from being used in case `background-clip: text` is not supported.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/0oeftdbk/5/

––

As per the  bug of the gradient not showing clipped inside the text on Safari, it looks like that if it's applied on the parent element and not directly to the children, all the children need to be `display: inline` or a inherently inline element such as `span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overlay with a gradient background, disable the interaction with the overlay and position it at the bottom of the list.

Take a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s96bzcua/1/

```
#overlay {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 99%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to disable all interaction with the overlay and wrap everything in a div with relative positioning so you can place the overlay at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I think you pasted my fiddle URL so if you have another example that would help a lot.

Comment: @PeterN Oh yes, you are right. https://jsfiddle.net/s96bzcua/1/ I updated the post.

Comment: Your example makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might sound weird but:

replace `transparent` with `rgba (0,0,0,0.0001)`

It doesn't work with `rgba (0,0,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

if you only have the ascii code on your Element, maybe you need a full-width character.

like: `I need show transparent text color + ' '`