# CSS linear-gradient in vuetify´s v-icon on iOS/Safari not working

Tags: css, ios, vue.js, safari, vuetify.js

First of all, I am a beginner and I do not know how to ask the question correctly, but I hope you can help me.

I am building a website based on vuejs, css and vuetify.
I use the ***"v-icon"*** and define the "linear-gradient" myself with CSS. In Windows and Andoid it works with all browsers.
But with iOS/Safari the icons are not displayed.

I got it right with the ***"v-btn"***

**What do I have to do so that the icons are displayed correctly in iOS/Safari?**

Here is the website: [holidaytimes.de](https://holidaytimes.de)

My code looks like this:

In Template:

```
<v-icon class="vicon-color-linear-gradient">mdi-calendar-month</v-icon>
```

In CSS:

```
.vicon-color-linear-gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(249, 164, 78, 100), rgba(219, 31, 38, 100)) !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent !important; /*same with rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)*/ 
}
```

In main.js:

```
 import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'; 
 import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
    
new Vue({
    vuetify,
    router,
    store,
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here you can see in two screenshots how it looks currently

[Screenshot in Windows/Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIGeG.png)

[Screenshot in iOS/Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Rxl.png)

If I have forgotten any information, just let me know and I will add it.

Comment: Welcome to the problem of making a single browser work because they want to be different. Anyway would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47819393/10975709?

Comment: @doesnotmatter I have also tried this, unfortunately did not work